# Android app links with assetlinks.json on WIX website

Tags: javascript, android, deep-linking, velo

I am implementing deep linking to my android app and it works only when clicking on a link with the desired url such as `https://mydomain.co.il` only outside browsers like in whatsapp etc.
I know that for making app links work from browser, the website needs to have `assetlinks.json` file located at `https://mydomain.co.il/.well-known/assetlinks.json` in order to verify that I am the owner of both the domain and the app.

So I do have the assetlinks.json file ready but does anyone know how can I put the file in that specific location (`https://mydomain.co.il/.well-known/assetlinks.json`) on my website when using Wix as the platform ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you guys ever figure this out?

Comment: Any update on this? Did you find that out?

Comment: Sorry guys. I ended up just migrating to wordpress then it's pretty much straight forward to do.

Answer (score 4):

I struggled to find a straightforward way to host the Android Digital Asset Links file on Wix. Found bits and pieces of help on the net. Tested my code and it seems to work.

Here it goes:

1. Android needs a Digital Asset Links file hosted on the website of an app to verify ownership. The link required is: `https://www.yoursite.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json`
2. Since hosting this file at that location was not a plausible solution on Wix (at least to me at the time of this post), we'll need to add a JS file which can spit out the same JSON data and then redirect the URL Google expects to our new link.
3. Go to Dev Mode -> Enable Developer Mode and switch on the developer mode
4. In the new left pane, go to {} (Public & Backend)
5. Next to Backend, click on +, and create a new Javascript file with the name `http-functions.js`
6. Add this code:

```
// Import the Wix http functions API 
import {ok, notFound, serverError} from 'wix-http-functions';  

// Set the assetlinks variable (between the single backticks) with the content of your assetlinks.json file 

let assetlinks = `[{
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target" : { "namespace": "android_app", "package_name": "<Your app package>",
                    "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["<Your app's SHA256>"] }
}]`  

// Define http get function for your trust.txt file 

export function get_assetlinks(request) {     
    let options = {         
        "headers": {             
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        },
        
        "body": assetlinks     
    };     
    return ok(options); 
}
```

7. Publish your site
8. Test if the JSON is displayed by calling: `www.yoursite.com/_functions/assetlinks`

Hoping that things are great so far, we'll proceed to the last and final step - URL redirection

1. Go to site Settings > Marketing & SEO > SEO Tools > URL Redirect Manager
2. Click on New Redirect and enter for:
   Old URL: /.well-known/assetlinks.json
   New URL: /_functions/assetlinks
3. Test out the link [www.yoursite.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json](http://www.yoursite.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json)

Hope this helps someone! Better late than never.

Comment: there's one typo: in step 5, the file name should be 'http-functions.js' so it has hyphen, not underbar. Then it works! Thanks!

Comment: Well, I got an error: basically saying 'redirection is not allowed'.

Comment: @BrianHong well noted. Corrected the typo.

Comment: @BrianHong were you able to figure this out?

Comment: I got it running using above. But according to this link Google don't allows any 301 or 302 redirects.
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks#publish-json.
So i contacted Wix support for any direct links and they simply excused

Comment: Great. I followed this approach but I am still not able to get this to working. When I try to verify this with App Links Assistant on Android Studio, it still throws up the error that Digital Asset Links file not found at https://www.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Comment: @VarunAM is your website hosted on Wix? What's does going to <yoursite.com>/.well-known/assetlinks.json give you?

Comment: @deetho It gives valid json but only after redirect. Looks like redirects are not allowed with Deeplinks in Android. I even checked with wix support and they said they currently don't support deeplink. Not sure what to do.